# Weird “3D” text being added to filenames in godot 4 on project imported from godot 3.5, causing scene to not load

Tags: godot

I tried importing a project from godot 3.5 to godot 4 and a bunch of the png files for the sprites are coming up as having “dependency issues” due to the the letters “3D” suddenly appearing in their file names.  Including screen shot for example.

This is a 2D game and it still runs just fine in 3.5, but was hoping to upgrade to 4.0 now that it’s released.  Is anyone else getting something like this?

The “3D” is only there according to godot - when I go and look at the actual files there’s no “3D”.  So for some reason Godot 4 is getting the idea that a bunch of these sprites have words that aren’t there in their filenames when doing the import/conversion from 3.5.

There are hundreds of these errors coming up, so not sure if there’s an easy solution other than manually going through each one and  reselecting the correct files for the dependencies.  Cause If that’s the case I’ll just keep using 3.5, ugh.[screenshot of png image file name now saying 3D in its text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe9dj.jpg)

Tried reimporting and also deleting import folders, none of that worked.  Going in and manually reselecting the correct files for each error seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This is Godot 4 trying to upgrade your Godot 3.x project. When you first open your Godot 3.x project in Godot 4, it will ask you if you want to automatically upgrade the whole project or just the project file.

Asking it to upgrade the whole project will replace the names of things that changed from Godot 3.x to Godot 4. That include most of the classes that derive from `Spatial` (now `Node3D`) which now have "3D" as part of the name (which makes them consistent with the classes that derive from `Node2D` that have "2D" as part of their name).

In your particular case, given the screenshot, the culprit is the `Light` class which is now called `Light3D`.

And yes, the upgrade tool is not good enough to tell these are filenames.

---

Usually you would be using text based files with Godot, such as `tscn` and `tres` (the "t" stands for "text") which also work better with version control (You are using version control, right?)… So you can use another tool - such as Visual Studio Code or similar - to search and replace in the files of the project.

For example, we can search for any string that say `Light3D` followed by some character valid in filenames that are not space, followed by `.png` using a regex like this:

```
Light3D([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)\.png
```

There I'm capturing with the parenthesis the characters between `Light3D` and `.png`, so we can replace with this:

```
Light$1.png
```

Where `$1` will be what we captured. Thus the only change would be removing `3D` from the text.

Please note that I'm including `Light` and `.png` in the search to make sure it is limited to the particular case, and it won't change what it should not.

Thus, you would do similarly for other cases you find. You can tell Godot to reload the project between changes and see what errors come up. And based on that decide what to replace next.